# What happen actually when TextBox got selected ? or got focused..?

Tags: c#, events

I am trying to code for "Hint Text in Text Box" in C#. It works this way:

1. Initially show "Hint Text" with inactive caption color
2. Blank the text box if all the hint text is selected
3. Shows the user input text (after typing in this)
4. If user deletes his text and goes to the next control, then it shows the hint text again.

I need a help on 2nd point: It's not clearing the text box if its content is not selected. It receives the input text mixed with "hint text".

On which event I need to write the code `txtBox1.Clear();` to achieve my aim?

Comment: What have you tried so far?  Also, with point #2: Is it only supposed to clear the hint text if the text itself is selected, or whenever the text box itself is selected?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming this is WinForms: Look at the `Enter` and `Leave` events. They will be called when a control gets or loses focus. You then need to decide whether the value in the text box is your default hint or entered by the user.

For WPF: There are nice solutions out there that use adorners to achieve what you want. You could google for `WPF textbox watermark adorner`.

Comment: Thanx... Actually this is winform and I used this leave and enter event. now it works....

Comment: @yogeshpatil Feel free to upvote or accept the answer.